# Rand() in TYPO3 Extbase Query

Tags: random, typo3, extbase

I'm using Extbase in TYPO3.

I want to create some repository function which can get a random record from the database.

Is there a way to resolve this with the Extbase Query Language?

Comment: Is that still an issue in 2018? I think so, but not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this issue:
http://forge.typo3.org/issues/14026

Seems like this is still a problem in Extbase.

But there is some workarounds like this one:
http://typo3blogger.de/random-record-repository/